# ArrayList contains

Tags: java, random

I don't really understand what's happening, if someone could explain this to me that would be great.

So, here's my code:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args){
    for(int i =0; i != 90; i++){
        System.out.println(generate());
    }
}

public static int generate(){
    Random random = new Random();
    int rand = random.nextInt(89)+1;

    while(numbers.contains(rand)){ //<---Here seems to be my problem
        rand = random.nextInt(89)+1;
        System.out.println("Number: " + rand + " already exists!");
    }
    numbers.add(rand);
    return rand;
}
```

I am writing a program that generates a random number from 0-90, each of which are different to the last. Unfortunately, it seems that the while loop only returns true.

Comment: You mean its caught in an 'infinite' loop?

Comment: "only returns true"? that cannot be what's happening...

Comment: The answers provided should help you solve your problems but also consider the flow of the generate loop. You first check for `numbers.contains(rand)` and then you immediately assign another random number to that same variable before you print that your list contains `rand`. You are printing out the altered data, not the original data that you entered the loop with. It probably added to your confusion when debugging. Being that almost every number exists before it tells you that the number was indeed added to the list, making it seem as if `generate()` was the problem.

Comment: If you want values from **0** to 90, why are you adding 1 to the result of `random.nextInt()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it easily by using collections shuffle

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i =1; i <= 90; i++){
    number.add(i)
}
Collections.shuffle(numbers); // at this point the number are shuffled.
```

Read about [shuffle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)).

Comment: Thanks for this, it's a much better solution than my program, although as the rest of my class are doing it in python, it would seem to be cheating.

Comment: I would think that this would be cheating, as it isn't your code and it doesn't demonstrate any lesson that would be taught at your level of learning.

Answer (score 10):

You're picking from 89 random numbers (1-89 inclusive) and trying to find a unique number each time... but you're calling that 90 times. What do you expect the last iteration to do? (To put it another way - you're trying to squeeze 90 numbers into 89 slots. That's not going to work.) On the last iteration, all the possible values will already be in the list, so the condition of your `while` loop will *always* be met, whatever value is randomly chosen on each iteration.

If you wanted the numbers to be between 1 and 90 inclusive, you should be using `random.nextInt(90) + 1`. The argument to `nextInt` is the maximum number *exclusive* to generate - so if you call `random.nextInt(3)` for example, it will generate 0, 1 or 2.

(There are better ways of doing this, by the way - such as populating the list and then using `Collections.shuffle` - but I've concentrated on explaining the behaviour of your current code.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that wasn't the question I asked although I changed this and am grateful.

Comment: @genfy: It's the answer to the question of "I don't really understand what's happening, if someone could explain this to me that would be great" - unlike the answer you accepted, which gives an alternative approach but doesn't explain your current code at all. If you didn't want to know what was going on, what *did* you want to know, and how was anyone meant to realize that? I may not have answered the question you wanted to ask - but I answered the question you *did* ask.